# SMD component marked X02X

Tags: components, surface-mount

Device: Audi Q7 Quick Ignition Cable TDB011
Board: TDB011-OBD M LED 12.16-1
Component: Missing (burned beyond recognition) SOT23. Most likely MOSFET (next to power input). There are another two such components on the same board (a very small board) and no other (one eception that is a diode), so I assume, it would be same as the others. But, of course, it may be something else :). However, with the owner's permission, I am willing accept the chance that it is the same.

Comment: This question would be *greatly* improved by the addition of pictures.

Comment: Welcome to the EE Stack Exchange. Your question, as it is currently phrased, reads like a puzzle. I request you to add schematics (if any) or at least a picture. Only you can edit your question to make it more coherent.